# The Aptana Debugger Addon for firefox were deactivated by firefox 53.03

Tags: javascript, html

Firefox says the Aptana debugger addon must be verifed by firefox.
How can I get it o work?

Regards
Wolfgang

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Mozilla Documentation on this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox#w_what-can-i-do-if-firefox-disables-an-installed-add-on) your options are to either get a signed version of the add on from the developer or (advanced mode) use a version of Firefox that lets you disable the requirement for signed add ons.

Choosing to use an unsigned add on is at your risk and not a decision you should make unless you absolutely trust the source of the add on.